# Difficulty with setInterval loop using class of Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, loops

```
$(document).ready(function fadeIt() {

    $("#cool_content > div").hide();

    var sizeLoop = $("#cool_content > div").length;
    var startLoop = 0;

    $("#cool_content > div").first().eq(startLoop).fadeIn(500);

    setInterval(function () {
        $("#cool_content > div").eq(startLoop).fadeOut(1000);

        if (startLoop == sizeLoop) {
            startLoop = 0
        } else {
            startLoop++;
        }

        $("#cool_content > div").eq(startLoop).fadeIn(1500);

    }, 2000);
});
```

Here I want a class of divs to animate, infinitely!

However, because the interval is set to two seconds there is period where no div is showing!

What would be an appropriate way to loop the animation of these divs?

I thought about using a for loop but couldn't figure out how to pass a class of divs as arguments. All your help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a fiddle as well! http://jsfiddle.net/aT9JB/

Comment: You should only go up to `sizeLoop - 1` instead of `sizeLoop` : http://jsfiddle.net/aT9JB/2/.

Comment: Samuel - ah what an idiot I am. There is no 5th div x_x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var divs = $('#cool_content > div').hide();
    var curDiv;
    var counter = 0;
    var doUpdate = function(){
        // Hide any old div
        if (curDiv)
            curDiv.fadeOut(1000);

        // Show the new div
        curDiv = divs.eq(counter);
        curDiv.fadeIn(1000);

        // Increment the counter
        counter = ++counter % divs.length;
    };
    doUpdate();
    setInterval(doUpdate, 2000);
});
```

This loops infinitely through the divs.  It's also more efficient than your code because it only queries the DOM for the list of divs once.

Update: [Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3efrJ/)

Comment: Very straight forward. Thank you! One day I will be able to do this without asking x_x

Answer (score 1):

Ok, generally, you should know that Javascript is a single threaded environment. Along with this, the timer events are generally not on time accurately. I'm not sure how jQuery is doing fadeIn and fadeOut, but if it's not using CSS3 transitions, it's going to be using timeOut and Intervals. So basically, there's a lot of timer's going on.

If you go with the for loop on this one, you'd be blocking the single thread, so that's not the way to go forward. You'd have to do the fade in/out by yourself in the setInterval.

Setting the opacity on each interval call. Like `div.css('opacity', (opacity -= 10) + '%')`

If you're trying to fade in and out sequentially, I think maybe this code would help

```
var opacity = 100,
    isFadingIn = false;
window.setInterval(function() {
    if (isFadingIn) {
        opacity += 10;
        if (opacity === 100) isFadingIn = false;
    } else {
        opacity -= 10;
        if (opacity === 0) isFadingIn = true;
    }

    $('#coolContent > div').css('opacity', opacity + '%');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: My comment didn't post. Thanks for the explanation. Definitely helps me in the way understanding JS

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if (startLoop == sizeLoop)
{
    startLoop = 0
}
else
{
    startLoop++;
}
```

use

```
startLoop =(startLoop+1)%sizeLoop;
```

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/JvdU9/  - 1st div is being animated just immediately after 4th disappears.

**UPD:**
Not sure I've undestood your question, but I'll try to answer :)
It doesn't matter how many divs you are being looped - 4, 5 or 10, since number of frames are being calculated automatically

`x=(x+1)%n` means that `x` will never be greater than `n-1`: `x>=0` and `x<n`.

`x=(x+1)%n` is just shorten equivalent for

```
if(x<n-1)
    x++;
else
    x=0;
```

as for me first variant is much readable:)
And sorry, I gave you last time wrong demo. Correct one - http://jsfiddle.net/JvdU9/2/

Comment: Quick question Ruslan (and any who want to contribute). For the % operator, is the code trying to make sense of 1/5? Basically, how is the code moving through the divs by way of a remainder?